# How can I center a responsive image

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I can't figure out how I can make a responsive image and at the same time make the image centered regardless if it is viewed on a cellphone or on a computer with a wider resolution.

I'm using css class `.img-responsive` but that always does align the image left. I checked on the fields set by that class but can't find out how to combine the different styles so that the image is responsive and at the same time centered.

It's a simple image contained within an `div` or `article` specified with a `row-fluid` class.

Comment: where do this classes come from? What CSS rules do they apply?

Comment: it all depends on what html and css you have.. there are several ways of centering an image, you need to provide the code you are using.

Answer (score 3):

This **CSS** will do it:

```
.img-responsive {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Note: In IE it works only for 9+

Answer (score 1):

Here what you want. [responsive image demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/responsive-image).

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/450/" class="ri" />

img.ri
{
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 80%;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}

img.ri:empty
{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  img.ri {
      max-width: 90%;
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  img.ri {
      max-height: 90%;
  }
}
```

You can use @media and other formatting property for it.

[Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-responsive-centered-image/) is a tutorial on it.

or you can also try :

```
img { 
     max-width:100%; max-height:100%; margin:auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one . Applying margin-left and margin-right to auto will solve your problem.

> ```
> <style>
> .center
> {
> margin-left:auto;
> margin-right:auto;
> }
> </style>
>
> <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
> <img class="img-responsive center"/>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

in this way ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/nMTQT/)) an image is centered horizzontally and vertically and is responsive

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go with `position: absolute` as it removes it from the layout context meaning it will likely, not be where you want it to be. Instead try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="centered-image-container">
    <img class="centered-image" src="">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.centered-image-container {
    text-align: center;
}
.centered-image {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a codepen with an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eHfrd

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
.product .img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```